# PHP Variable from extended class

Tags: php, class, oop

I cant retrieve var from parent class:

```
class core {
    var $variable;
    var $test;

    function __construct() {}

    public function setVar($var) 
        $this->variable = $var;
    }
}

class test extends core {
    public function getVar() {
        return $this->variable;
        //also if i echo here i can't see !!!!
    }
}

$core = new core();
$core->setVar("ok");
$core->test = new test();
print $core->test->getVar();
```

Any help??

Comment: This doesn't make much sense: You are creating a child object inside `$core`. What are you trying to achieve exactly? Also, `var` is PHP 4; in PHP 5, it's better to use the `public` / `private` / `protected` keywords for properties.

Answer (score 1):

You do not seem to understand the difference between static and instance variables. Static variables exist only once and are accessible through any instance of the class, while for instance variables, each object has a different version of the variable, and setting the variable on another object does not effect it.

```
class Test {
    public $instance = 0;
    public static $static = 0;
    // ... getters, setters
}

// create two instances of class Test
$first = new Test();
$second = new Test();

$first->setInstance(1);
$first->setStatic(1);

$second->getInstance(); // 0
$second->getStatic(); // 1
```

So in your case, `$core->variable` and `$core->test->variable` are two different variables, and setting one has no effect on the other. If you declared  `$variable` as static, then they would be the same variable.

Comment: +1 for stating something I think we've all been guilty of at some point.  Sometimes the simplest comments solve the most complex issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

class core{

    var $variable;
    var $test;

    function __construct() {}

    public function setVar($var) {
      $this->variable = $var;
    }

}


class test extends core {

    public function getVar() {

       return $this->variable;
       //also if i echo here i can't see !!!!
    }

}

$test = new test(); // will call core->__construct()
$test->setVar(5); // this isn't being called with your original code
print $test->getVar(); // now you can call this and get back "5"

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, class names in PHP starts with a capital letter : Core, Test, but this is only convention.

Then, you never assign a value to $variable, so when you call `getVar()`, the method returns nothing.

And like already said, `var` is an old syntax, you should now give a visibility to your variable with `public`, `protected` or `private` like in C++ or Java. In your case, you want to use `public` or `protected`.

Finally, your code doesn't make much sense. Usually getter and setter are defined at the same level (ie the same class) and there's no point in instantiating a `Test` object in a variable from `Core`. This create a dependency between `Core` and `Test` which is totally wrong from an OOP point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Don't debug with echo or print !! Use var_dump () !

```
var_dump($core->test->getVar());
```

your mistake will become evident !
Also consider putting this line at the beginning of the script:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, `$variable` does not hold a value,

you need to set a value like so:

```
$core = new core();
$core->test = new test();
$core->setVar("Something");

print $core->test->getVar(); //Something
```